# How do I convert DateTime .NET datatype to W3C XML DateTime data type string and back?

Tags: c#, .net, string, types

I have a `System.DateTime` object and I need to convert it into a string storing that datetime in W3C XML DateTime format (yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ) and then be able to convert the resulting string back into `System.DateTime`.

Is there something ready for that in .NET or do I have to implement it myself?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I thought W3C dateTime had a lot more significant digits for the time.
Here's what I use:

```
// DateTime to W3C dateTime string
string formatString= "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffzzz";
dateTimeField.ToString(formatString) ;

// W3C dateTime string to DateTime 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo cInfo= new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", true);
dateTimeField= System.DateTime.ParseExact(stringValue, formatString, cInfo);
```

Answer (score 15):

If you want a date in the W3C XML format, then use .Net's W3C XML formatting API (been there since before v1.0):

```
var w3cStringFormat = XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime.Now);
```

results in:

2014-09-12T16:03:22.6833035+01:00

Then to get it back again:

```
var dateTime = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(w3cStringFormat);
```

Comment: XMLConvert should be XmlConvert in the first code snippet.

Comment: According to MSDN, "The XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime) method is obsolete in the 2.0 version of the .NET Framework and has been replaced with the XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode) method." — https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zds88xsz(v=vs.110).aspx

It still works, though.

Comment: I'm doing this instead: XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime.Now, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Local). Other serialization modes here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldatetimeserializationmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5):

This will convert to the string you need and parse back the string to the DateTime:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(now.ToUniversalTime().ToString());
var nowString = now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
Console.WriteLine(nowString);

var nowAgain = DateTime.ParseExact(nowString, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", null);
Console.WriteLine(nowAgain.ToUniversalTime().ToString());

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think [**JSON.net**](http://json.codeplex.com/) can handle it.
Use **IsoDateTimeConverter**.

From documentation:

```
public class LogEntry
{
  public string Details { get; set; }
  public DateTime LogDate { get; set; }
}

[Test]
public void WriteJsonDates()
{
  LogEntry entry = new LogEntry
  {
    LogDate = new DateTime(2009, 2, 15, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
    Details = "Application started."
  };

  string defaultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry);
  // {"Details":"Application started.","LogDate":"\/Date(1234656000000)\/"}

  string javascriptJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry, new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
  // {"Details":"Application started.","LogDate":new Date(1234656000000)}

  string isoJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry, new IsoDateTimeConverter());
  // {"Details":"Application started.","LogDate":"2009-02-15T00:00:00Z"}
}
```

Comment: Makes sense if he is embedding it into JSON.  Otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

Xml Serialization is there for you. Below is the code how to:-

```
DateTime someDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(DateTime));
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
// converting to w3c xml
ser.Serialize(ms, someDateTime);

//**Edited**
ms.Position = 0;
//**Edited**

System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(ms);
string w3cxml = sr.ReadToEnd();

sr.Close();
ms.Close();

// doing reverse
System.IO.StringReader reader = new System.IO.StringReader(w3cxml);

DateTime thatDateTime = (DateTime)ser.Deserialize(reader);

reader.Close();
```